# Scale an image multiple times

Tags: javascript, css

The script below is working in zooming an image using transform scale if I click + or - button for the first time.The second time I click the button it doesn't zoom. How can I zoom image on the succeding clicks? 
HTML

```
<div="myImage">
<input type="button" value="+" onclick="javascript:btnZoomInplus();"/>
<input type="button" value="-" onclick="javascript:btnZoomOutminus();"/>

<img src="vegetable.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Script

```
function btnZoomInplus(){   
        document.getElementById('myDiv1').style.webkitTransform = 'scale(1)';               
}
 function btnZoomOutminus(){     
  document.getElementById('myDiv1').style.webkitTransform = 'scale(0.5)';
}
```

Comment: Have you tried saving the scale in a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are going to want to keep a multiplier variable. The transform is always applied to your original content, so you keep transforming it by 1

```
var multiplier = 1;
function btnZoomInplus(){  
   multiplier = multiplier + 0.5;
   zoom();             
}

function btnZoomOutminus(){     
   multiplier = multiplier - 0.5;
   zoom();
}

function zoom() {

   document.getElementById('myDiv1').style.webkitTransform = 'scale('+ multiplier +')';  
}
```

Same goes for your zoom out.

Of course you can add checks not to go below 0 and not above a certain max zoom amount.

Comment: Thanks Heinrich! it works. I'm quite ashamed why I never thought about it lol!